# Can't send file and string to nodejs using react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to make an input form, the form includes string and file
but I got some problem I can send the file to the server, but I can't send the string to the server, My question is how to send string and file to the server together.

This is my client code

```
const [myFile, setmyFile] = useState("");

const onFileUpload = () => {
    try {
      const data = new FormData();
      const mystring = { makan: "ikan", suka: "mati" };
      data.append("tmparr", myFile);
      data.append("tmparr", mystring);
      Axios.post("http://localhost:10000/uploads", data).then((res) => {
        console.log(res.statusText);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error while uploading image to server", error);
    }
  };

<div>
        <h1>GeeksforGeeks</h1>
        <h3>File Upload using React!</h3>
        <div>
          <input
            type="file"
            onChange={(event) => {
              setmyFile(event.target.files[0]);
            }}
          />
          <button onClick={onFileUpload}>Upload!</button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

This is my server code

```
const upload = multer({ dest: "uploads/" });

app.post("/uploads", upload.any("tmparr", 20), async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req);
})
```

In the server I try to `console.log(req);`, to show what I can get from req and I got return this

```
  body: [Object: null prototype] { tmparr: '[object Object]' },
  route: Route {
    path: '/uploads',
    stack: [ [Layer], [Layer] ],
    methods: { post: true }
  },
  files: [
    {
      fieldname: 'tmparr',
      originalname: 'sertif.jpg',
      encoding: '7bit',
      mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
      destination: 'uploads/',
      filename: 'f24f5a1555e908b2c7725eab36925a0e',
      path: 'uploads\\f24f5a1555e908b2c7725eab36925a0e',
      size: 208744
    }
  ],
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
  [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
```

As you can see, I can get the file in `req.files`, but  the string return object `body: [Object: null prototype] { tmparr: '[object Object]' },`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to use `fromidable`

This is the client code

```
const [myFile, setmyFile] = useState("");

  const onFileUpload = () => {
    try {
      const data = new FormData();
      const mystring = { makan: "ikan", suka: "mati" };
      data.append("tmparr", myFile);
      data.append("tmparr", mystring);
      Axios.post(url + "uploads", data).then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error while uploading image to server", error);
    }
  };
```

This is server code

```
app.post("/uploads", async (req, res, next) => {
  const form = formidable({ multiples: true });
  form.parse(req, (err, string, files) => {
    if (err) {
      next(err);
      return;
    }
    res.json({ string, files });
  });
});
```

[This is the result what I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlOYf.png)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly for the `mystring` that you are referring too I seem to not see it in your state I only see the  `myFile` so the way you are sending the data to the server I cannot fault that

So now how you can handle things in at the back-end the most easiest way and beginner friendly is make use of this other npm package `formidable`

- Easy to use check docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable

Comment: you mean my client not wrong ? I'm really confused to use formidable , I try it but mystring still return object , can you give me a example client and server , client use reactjs , server use nodejs , thanks :)

Comment: I will edit my answer in a few hours(busy with exam) giving you a detailed explanation in as far as implementation is concerned for both client-side and server-side

Comment: Thank you bro good luck for your exam , I will post new comment in bottom , it contain what I have tried and the result

Answer (score -1):

try to put them inside an object:-

```
  const onFileUpload = () => {
    try {
      const fileData = new FormData();
      const mystring = { makan: "ikan", suka: "mati" };
      const data = {
        tampar: fileData.append("tmparr", myFile)
        tamparr: myString 
      }
      
      Axios.post("http://localhost:10000/uploads", data).then((res) => {
        console.log(res.statusText);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error while uploading image to server", error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: When using ```FormData``` you do not have to do that already when he said ```fileData.append(key, value)``` that what formdata does meaning no need to add another key as object will result to that